# View Controller opening (via Show segue) in a weird way

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

As you can see in the video here, the view controller opens in a weird way (stretched with grey/black colour at the top) and then gets back normal.
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K9NQkEs7xxaHfEx83XTgcWd7j200tBXp/view?usp=sharing

I want to avoid this. I want View Controller normally as it would. I am unable to understand how to proceed. What may be the possible reasons behind it and how do I do correct it?

Comment: How are you pushing the second viewcontroller? Can you please show us some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as though it is laying out for a large title in the navigation bar.

Try adding this to the `viewDidLoad` method of the controller.

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

Answer (score 0):

Just disable large title in viewDidLoad. **And do it only since iOS 11**:

```
    func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
              if #available(iOS 11, *) {
                self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
              }
     ...
```

Comment: Instead of duplicating @Callam's answer. You can improve his answer.